# Why isn't my bullet moving by using rb.velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, bullet

I'm trying to make a little space shooter game all by myself and I ran into a problem when trying to make my bullet prefab. I'm setting its velocity in the start method and when I press play it isn't moving at all.

```
public float speed;
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
}
```

I'm using rb.velocity in my player script too, to move him and it works just fine.

Comment: Two questions: 1) is "speed" correctly initialized for both the objects? 2) Do you have the same value of "is kinematic" on the two objects' rigidbody?

Comment: Speed is initialized in the inspector for both objects. What is the rigidbody2d kinematic ? I know the normal rigidbody has kinematic but I don't see it in the 2d one

Comment: Mmm, nice point: I'm not sure if you have it in the interface, but you can set it also by code: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-isKinematic.html. By the way, it's just a suggestion, can't be sure if it could help...

Comment: Yeah I made it work somehow, I just abandoned the idea of using velocity and using addForce.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you put rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed; into the Start function.

Try this script instead

```
public float speed;
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void Update()
{
    rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
}
```